# (Re)boot an Android phone from USB

Tags: adb, usb, boot, reboot

I own a Samsung Galaxy Note 1 (*not* rooted) and its lock button doesn't wrok anymore. That means I couldn't boot my phone if it happened to be turned off.

But I need to restart it now because it's buggy.

Do you know a tool on PC that would allow me to call for a reboot via USB ? (The *USB debugging* option is activated).

If not, do you know a way to boot an Android phone without this Lock button ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Real Reboot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.anothermobile.realreboot&hl=en)

- Works on Android 2.1 - 4.2.1 **No Root**
- 4.2.2 and up **needs root**.

---

For a PC method you will be using Android Debug Bridge, commonly called ADB. Here is a [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979) for a download. It's from the XDA Forums. Read the page while your there and get some good insight on ADB.

After installed to the computer, open a command prompt (L shift + R mouse click) in the folder that has the ADB file. Make sure you have your device drivers installed and the phone plugged into the USB on the PC.

- Type : ***adb devices*** (make sure device is seen)
- Then: ***adb reboot*** (reboots device)

Here is a [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) to the Android Developers website that will give you full detail about the inner workings of ADB

Comment: Real Reboot works fine, it will do the trick until I get a new phone. Thanks!

Comment: That's what we're all here for :)

Comment: Just FYI,  the link I provided for download is a minimal installation of ADB & FASTBOOT, without the whole SDK. Its just to have everything work, so no huge install.

Answer (score 0):

**If you're rooted :**

Just search for any app that restarts the phone. Just search on play store  -  "Restart". That'll do the work...

**If you're not rooted** 
As HasH_BrowN told, adb is the solution.

The first step is to have USB debugging turned on, which you have.
Now, follow these steps :

1. Install adb and your phone's drivers on your PC/Mac/Linux machine. This is a good guide, if you haven't installed it already : http://lifehacker.com/the-easiest-way-to-install-androids-adb-and-fastboot-to-1586992378
2. Once done, go to the directory where adb is installed (I'm assuming you're on windows. If you're on mac or linux, just skip this step.)
3. Open command prompt/terminal in this directory.
4. Connect your phone via usb to your computer
5. In the terminal, execute this command : `adb devices` 
   If it says no devices found, then you've not installed your device drivers. Search how to install Note 1 drivers on PC/Mac/Linux. 
   Otherwise, it'll show you the device ID and the name.
6. Execute `adb -s <device ID> reboot`  - insert the device ID you got on the previous command in this command.

This'll reboot your cellphone or for that matter any android device.
You can also write a shell script which does this, so you don't have to write all the commands again and again, and just a double click would do.

Hope this helps.

Comment: All the apps that restart the phone need a root access, which I don't have. All the ones I saw, of course.

Comment: I've edited my post. Let me know if this works now.

Comment: I chose to use the Real Reboot app, but thank you for improving your answer and adding a simple guide to install ADB without the entire Android SDK.

Comment: The device ID in step 6 isn't necessary for a reboot. Plus your answer is mimicking mine. Good job on the edit.

Comment: HasH_BrowN I made the edit almost at the same time when you answered. I hadn't seen your reply then. Secondly, it's good to specify device id, say in case any other linux based device is also connected to one's machine, then it shouldn't reboot that too. I had no intentions of mimicking your answer or anything as such. Take a chill pill. His question got answered, that's all that's required.

Comment: I made a comment, now you don't get snappy - (chill pill)

Comment: You would only need to input a device ID, if when you typed **adb devices** and it returned multiple devices. (Good point though)